# use lapply within ifelse and maintain column names

Tags: r

I have df1 sorted by date like this:

```
Date <- c("12/17/17","12/19/17","12/20/17","12/30/17","12/31/17","1/1/18")
Jon <- c(388,299,412,NA,NA,353)
Eric <- c(121,NA,321,473,832,NA)
Scott <- c(NA,122,NA,NA,NA,424)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Jon,Eric,Scott)
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date,format='%m/%d/%y')

#df1
    Date        Jon   Eric  Scott
1   12/17/17    388   121   NA
2   12/19/17    299   NA    122
3   12/20/17    412   321   NA
4   12/30/17    NA    473   NA
5   12/31/17    NA    832   NA
6   1/1/18      353   NA    424
```

I'm trying to create a new list that includes only the data that is within the last 12 days of each person's most recent date with a non-NA value. If there is only one non-NA value within 12 days of the person's most recent non-NA value, then I want to take the 2 most recent non-NA values for that person, even if one falls outside of the 12 day date range.

The code below successfully puts data within the last 12 days of each person's most recent non-NA value in a new list:

```
df2 <- lapply(df1[-1],function(x) x[which((m=tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=12)])
```

This code successfully takes the 2 most recent non-NA entries, regardless of whether or not it's within the 12 day range:

```
df3 <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], n = 2))
```

This code comes very close to doing what I want it to do, except it loses the column names. Notice that the column names are replaced with numbers, unlike the lapply statements above, which both keep the column names.

```
withinRange <-lapply(df1[-1],function(x)x[which((m=tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=12)]) %>%
    lapply(function(x)length(x[!is.na(x)])) %>%
    as.data.frame() 
df4 <- ifelse(withinRange[colnames(df1[-1])]>1,lapply(df1[-1],function(x) x[which((m=tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=12)]),lapply(df1[-1], function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], n = 2)))
```

How can I maintain the column names?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem using the `tidyverse` packages.

#### Data

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  my_date = as.Date(
    c("12/17/17", "12/19/17", "12/20/17", "12/30/17", "12/31/17", "1/1/18"),
    "%m/%d/%y"
  ),
  jon = c(388, 299, 412, NA, NA, 353),
  eric = c(121, NA, 321, 473, 832, NA),
  scott = c(NA, 122, NA, NA, NA, 424)
)
```

#### Long format data frame

This output feels more natural.

```
df_long <- df %>%
  gather(key, value, -my_date) %>%
  drop_na %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(
    in_date = if_else(my_date >= max(my_date) - days(12), TRUE, FALSE),
    count = sum(in_date)
  ) %>%
  filter(in_date | count < 2) %>%
  top_n(2, my_date) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-c(in_date, count))

df_long

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   my_date    key   value
#   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1 2017-12-20 jon     412
# 2 2018-01-01 jon     353
# 3 2017-12-30 eric    473
# 4 2017-12-31 eric    832
# 5 2017-12-19 scott   122
# 6 2018-01-01 scott   424
```

#### Wide format

Thankfully, it is only one additional step to spread to your original columns.

```
df_long %>% spread(key, value)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   my_date     eric   jon scott
# * <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2017-12-19    NA    NA   122
# 2 2017-12-20    NA   412    NA
# 3 2017-12-30   473    NA    NA
# 4 2017-12-31   832    NA    NA
# 5 2018-01-01    NA   353   424
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid `gather` due to the size of my data. It is somewhat slow.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest thing to do for me is to store the column headers in a variable and then reattach them:

```
myHeaders <- names(df1[-1])
withinRange <-lapply(df1[-1],function(x)x[which((m=tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=12)]) %>%
   lapply(function(x)length(x[!is.na(x)])) %>%
   as.data.frame() 
df4 <- ifelse(withinRange[colnames(df1[-1])]>1,lapply(df1[-1],function(x) x[which((m=tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=12)]),lapply(df1[-1], function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], n = 2)))
names(df4) <- myHeaders
```